# Can a single Azure Static WebApp host multiple Angular applications?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

I use the same Azure Static WebApp to host multiple docs.
Each doc is an Angular application maintained by a team.

I have a pipeline that deploys every doc dist in the `docs` directory of the Azure Static WebApp :

```
/docs/angular-app-1
/docs/angular-app-2
```

My Azure pipeline looks like this :

```yaml
   - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
     inputs:
       is_static_export: true
       app_location:docs
       skip_app_build: true
       skip_api_build: true
       azure_static_web_apps_api_token: SOME_TOKEN
```

The `baseHref` of each Angular application varies:

angular-app-1: `baseHref="/angular-app-1/"`
angular-app-2: `baseHref="/angular-app-2/"`

To prevent 404 error when refreshing a page, a navigation fallback to `index.html` of each Angular app is required.
To achieve this, I added a `routes.json` file into `docs` directory:

```json
{
   "routes": [
     {
       "route": "/angular-app-1/*",
       "serve": "angular-app-1/index.html",
       "statusCode": 200
     }
     {
       "route": "/angular-app-2/*",
       "serve": "angular-app-2/index.html",
       "statusCode": 200
     },
   ]
}
```

It works as expected but `routes.json` is deprecated since months in favor of `staticwebapp.config.json`.

Is there a way to configure a navigation fallback per Angular application with the new configuration file ?

```json
{
     "navigationFallback": {
         "rewrite": "index.html"
     }
}
```

In my case `navigationFallback.rewrite` should be :

- `angular-app-1/index.html` for `angular-app-1`
- `angular-app-2/index.html` for `angular-app-2`

I have tried putting a `staticwebapp.config.json` file with the appropriate navigation fallback in each Angular application distribution, but without success.

I can't figure out how to convert `routes.json` configuration to `staticwebapp.config.json`

Could this possibility of rewriting according to a route have been forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`routes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#define-routes) property in the new configuration file that can be used.

You would need something like this

```json
{
  ...
  routes: [
     {
       "route": "/angular-app-1/*",
       "rewrite": "/angular-app-1/index.html",
       "statusCode": 200
     },
     {
       "route": "/angular-app-2/*",
       "rewrite": "/angular-app-2/index.html",
       "statusCode": 200
     }
  ],
  ...
}
```